# terraform destroy specified resources concurrently

Tags: terraform

If I have a few different resources, I can destroy them all with one command like this:

```
terraform destroy -target=aws_instance.bake -target=aws_instance.ec2 -target=aws_db_instance.main
```

However, it destroys them sequentially, which might take a lot of time.  I'm wondering how I can destroy them concurrently.

Comment: If the `DELETE` operations are sequential, then that conveys a dependency relationship between the resources, and therefore this cannot be safely performed concurrently. It is also possible that the `DELETE` operations are actually concurrent, but you are interpreting the logs as implying they are sequential.

Comment: Did my answer work for you?

Answer (score 3):

`terraform destroy` is an alias for `terraform apply -destroy`, and `terraform apply` has a default `-parallelism` of 10, meaning terraform will process up to 10 resources at a time. So by default, terraform is *already* destroying the resources in parallel. You can of course change this argument to a lower or higher value as needed.

terraform however will not be able to delete resources in parallel when dependencies amongst them exist.